# making http request by ajax or c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, http-request, .net-core

In my web application I need to get data from Wikidata, for example to show item's details. I thought about using ajax for this, but was't sure from where I should to call it, so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527983/asp-net-core-and-ajax).

But after some thinking, why should I use ajax? I can make http request from my server side code (C#). I can put it into controller, get information from Wikidata, fill out ViewModel and then call View(ViewModel).

What can be some downsides of this? Will it affect performance?

So, question is: ajax or C#?

**UPDATE**: Before development starting I was thinking if I should develop client part (HTML, JavaScript) and Web API separately. In this case I would use Ajax of course. But I decided at this stage I'll do one MVC application. Because it has server side code anyway (even in View), so I think that http request from C# looks more naturally than JavaScript request.

Comment: So instead of using a well-known, well-understood API to get your data, you want to scrape a web page?

Comment: @Robert_Harvey, no, why scraping? I use the same API, actually SPARQL query, I can just call it from ajax or from C#.

Comment: Actually, you would call it from Javascript or C#.  AJAX is a *technique.*  So you're calling an XML web service from either C# or Javascript.  Which one you choose depends on what your requirements are.  If you need the data to go directly to the browser, you use Javascript.  If you want the data to go to the server first, to be inserted into the web page via ASP.NET MVC, you would use C#.

Comment: of course it's JavaScript, just use jQuery and Ajax

Comment: Yes.  So figure out if you want the data to come directly to the browser and bind it to some DOM elements via some mechanism like Knockout or just plain Javascript, or if you want it to go directly to the server and insert it into your View there.

Comment: updated question. Yes, if I use MVC I think I should use controller and ViewModel than send data to browser directly.

Comment: Sounds sensible to me.

Comment: actually I'm still not sure it's right decision to make one MVC application, but probably it can be easy for me to release it faster.

Comment: A general rule is that when page is loaded server-side then all data should be loaded server-side. AJAX is alternative to server-side loading and should be used in pure client-side apps.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the overriding reason for making a 3rd party API call server side is that it requires you to have an account, username and password with the 3rd party.

If you make the call client side then you expose this information to the user of your website/app

There are other reasons to consider, perhaps you merge the api data with some other data you only have serverside, perhaps you have more than one provider for the same data and want to switch between them but still provide the same datamodel to your client etc. perhaps javascript just isn't good enough to run your business logic

But, these are more meta-programming concerns about ease of maintainability etc. given the cost of a server side call and the extra step in the network traffic, if you can push it to the client it is usually a good thing to do.